# Query was empty while submitting the form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

/***Form design***/

```
    <html>
        <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    </head>

        <body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action=""><label><center>Register Form</center></label>
      <p><center></center><label>Name:</label>
      &nbsp; 
      <input type="text" name="name"></center>
    </p>
      <p><label>Rollno:</label>&nbsp; 
        <input type="text" name="rno"> 
      </p>
      <p><label>Address:</label>&nbsp; 
        <input type="text" name="add"> 
      </p>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
    </form>
```

/***********PHP******************/
/***Form submission***/

```
    <?php 
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("alpha") or die( "Unable select database");
    // Check connection
    // escape variables for security
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'],$con);
    $rno = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['rno'],$con);
    $add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add'],$con);

    $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (name, rno, add)
    VALUES ('$name','$rno','$add')",$con);
    $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!mysql_query($result,$con)) {
      die(mysql_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
        mysql_close($con);
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

some one please help me with this error.
i am getting the message query was empty.
how can i fix this.
i am new to php and my sql.
i dont know how to solve this issue.

Comment: echo $sql and check if you are getting the values in the query

Comment: You should use the `print_r($something);` for the lines in the code which you think could be wrong and find where is the problem by yourself, also i the `action=""` is empty, check again.

Comment: Try to avoid attributes like `name="name"` http://jibbering.com/faq/names/

Comment: By the way,  `mysql_real_escape_string()` is deprecated, see [PHP Manual](http://it1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("alpha") or die( "Unable select database");
// Check connection
// escape variables for security
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$rno = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['rno']);
$add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add']);

$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (name, rno, add) VALUES ('$name','$rno','$add')",$con);

if ($sql) {
    echo "1 record added";        
}
else {
    die(mysql_error($con));
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query should execute a query :

```html
  <?php 
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("alpha") or die( "Unable select database");
    // Check connection
    // escape variables for security
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'],$con);
    $rno = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['rno'],$con);
    $add = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['add'],$con);

    $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO test (name, rno, add)
              VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')", $name, $rno, $add);

    $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
    if (!$result) {
       $message  = 'Invalid request : ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
       $message .= 'Your query : ' . $query;

      die($message);
    }

      // @see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php
      echo mysql_affected_rows()  + " record added";

      mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you have kept your html form code and php code in the same page, you will need a conditional operator to check whether the form has been submitted or not. In your code above, the php code are executed even when the form is not submitted.

Make sure your form data are fetched by using any of the following:

```
var_dump($_POST);
print_r($_POST);
```

If it displays the data you have entered then so far you are good.

In your code above you have:

```
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

When you have done the above, you will not need the following code as the die() function will do the same. And the following code will also make your query run twice.

```
    if (!mysql_query($result,$con)) {
      die(mysql_error($con));
    }
```